# access web server host on same server as openVPN

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have OpenVPN and Web server hosted on the same server. I know that I can access the server by using the tunnel's IP but i want to be able to access the web server (with virtual host enabled) by using Domain name, linked to the same server.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and openvpn easy rsa

Edit:
What I want to achieve is to access my server by using domain name/public IP while I am connecting my VPN (OpenVPN)

Currently, the only way that I could access my server is via tunnel IP. I have heard that I could set some rules in IPTables to achieve this but after some research I was out of luck.

I used Masquerade rules to enable internet access from Wan to Tun.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the problem here.

Let's assume that your server have the IP 1.1.1.1 and VPN IP 10.0.0.1
Is your web server listening on VPN IP only?
Then you need to add your domain name to the hosts file on your local PC like:

```
10.0.0.1    mydomain.com
```

After that you'll access your web server using domain name.

Take a look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/3-things-you-should-know-about-dns.html) for more info about DNS related issues.

Comment: Hi I've just add an edit to my original post. Let me know if I need to clarify anything